# Melhores praticas ao utilizar SqlCommand? Text ou StoredProcedure?

Tags: c#, tsql

Estou querendo saber qual das seguintes abordagens é melhor?

1 - Adicionar um arquivo `*.sql` como *Resource*, então executar o *SqlCommand* com o `CommandType.Text`.

2 - Adicionar uma *Store Procedure* ao Banco de Dados, então executar o *SqlCommand* com o `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

O *Resource* com o SQL e a *Store Procudere* possuem a mesma consulta e esperam os mesmos parâmetros.

Em ambos os casos, os parâmetros são adicionados a lista de `Parameters` do *SqlCommand* e não temos SQL e C# misturados dentro do arquivo `*.cs`.

Neste cenário é mais rápido executar a *StoreProcedude* ou *Text*?

Comment: Você pode, ou melhor, deve medir para saber qual é o mais rápido. Não há uma diferença técnica que por si só determine qual é o mais rápido. A melhor performance vai depender do que este comando SQL faz e do que você faz com o resultado dele.

Comment: @Caffé, No caso seria apenas operações de leitura retornando uma lista de objetos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Neste cenário é mais rápido executar a *StoredProcedure* ou *Text*?

*StoredProdecure* é mais rápido. [De acordo com esse artigo](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/01/11/is-there-and-overhead-to-rpc-events.aspx), usar *Text* faz o objeto chamar **sp_executesql**, o que cria certo *overhead*  para criar os parâmetros e mais as verificações de ordem e preenchimento que o comando necessita para executar.

Além disso, se os parâmetros são opcionais, para o caso de *Text* é necessário passar todos os parâmetros, **mesmo que os opcionais nem sejam preenchidos**.

Comment: obrigado, estava deixando passar a questão do overhead gerado pelo sp_executesql.